# Нужна помощь для таймера на Python

Tags: python-3.x

Доброго времени суток, господа. Нужно сделать бота в Телеграмм, который при команде /aler ставит таймер на 30 секунд и регистрирует каждого пользователя, который пропишет /aler в течении этого времени. После того, как таймер останавливается, нужно всем, кто прописал команду присвоить рандомное число до 1000, и у кого оно будет больше - выйдет победителем. Я представляю себе логику примерно так:
`Тут условие: если боту пришла команда от юзера с id админа и не прошло после этого 30 секунд, то:
Ловить все команды от пользователей и записывать их id в бд/куда угодно и туда же рандомное число`
К сожалению, моих знаний пока не хватает на реализацию этого бота. Не подскажите, как это провернуть?

Comment: И как вы видите ответ? В виде готового кода?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов нет конечно, мне просто непонятно какие модули нужно использовать, и как нужно реализовать привязку к id рандомного числа.

Comment: Можно и на обычном map сделать: m[id] = random() и никакие модули не нужны

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, всё равно не понимаю. Можете дать пример?

Comment: Черт, оно в питоне не map, а dictionary называется. Попутал. Читайте про словари и списки.